# Android RelativeLayout overlapping

Tags: android

I've a relative layout in android for a chat application.The problem is that the listview on my screen when grows the last elements are hidden behind the textbox and button which I've placed at the bottom.

[image]

I am using the following layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout     
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/PreviousChatsButton"
      android:padding="5dip"
      android:text="@string/ViewPreviousChats"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:focusable="true"
      >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/NoChatsMsg"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/NoNewChatMsg"
          />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/SubmitButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/Submit"
    android:onClick="SubmitButtonClick" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Chatbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/SubmitButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/SubmitButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/SubmitButton"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you want to do is in the `LinearLayout` do `android:layout_above="@+id/Chatbox"` that will make sure it does not go below it

Answer (score 2):

//try this its working fine for me

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PreviousChatsButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="ViewPreviousChats" >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NoChatsMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/NoNewChatMsg" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SubmitButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="SubmitButtonClick"
            android:text="@string/Submit" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Chatbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/SubmitButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/SubmitButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/SubmitButton"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`android:layout_above`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_above) to avoid this problem :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SubmitButton" ... />

    <LinearLayout     
         android:layout_above="@id/SubmitButton" ... >
         ...
    </LinearLayout>
```

Note that you have to declare your button before the LinearLayout for this to work.